# Relationship between return value and garbage value

Tags: c, return-value, undefined-behavior

What happens if the return statement does not produce a return value in a function that produces a return value in C language? Does the compiler use garbage values in this case? Is this called undefined behavior?

For example;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func() {

    
}

int main() {
    int result = func();
    printf("Result: %d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Output of this code :
Result: 0

I am expecting this is a undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes this is UB (Undefined Behavior). It means anything can happen, including the situation where the program seems to work.

Comment: Be very careful.  You say "garbage value" as if there were distinct things that could be recognized as such.  There are not. Being a "garbage value" is about *provenance*, not about the value itself.  A value is a garbage value because the means by and circumstances under which it was obtained do not provide for that value to be meaningful for any purpose.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Under C99, ever object would either hold a value of its associated type or a trap representation; an object which held an "indeterminate value" would either hold a value of its type or a trap representation.

Comment: @supercat, I'm not sure offhand what distinction you're making between C99 and other versions of the language, and I'm especially unclear how it's related to my earlier remark.  To be sure, indeterminate values are what I would mean if I described something as a "garbage value", but to the best of my knowledge, you cannot recognize those by examining memory any more in C99 than in any other version of C.

Comment: In C99, accessing a storage location that held indeterminate value could only invoke UB if the type of the storage in question was one that had trap representations.

Answer (score 3):

C 2018 6.9.1 12 says:

> Unless otherwise specified, if the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

It is “otherwise specified” for the `main` function, because there are special rules for it in C 2018 5.1.2.2.3 1. For the function `func` in the question, it is not otherwise specified. when `func` is executed, program control reaches the `}` that terminate `func`. Then, in the caller, `main`, the return value of `func` is used. Therefore, the behavior of this program is not defined by the C standard.

> What happens if the return statement does not produce a return value in a function that produces a return value in C language?

If a called function and a calling function are compiled in separate source files and there is no extra communication between the object modules, such as link-time optimization information, then the compiler cannot see, when compiling the calling function, that the called function does not return a value. So the compiler must generate instructions that work if the function does return a value. In this case, the calling routine expects the function to return a value, so the instructions in it will fetch the value from the place where a value should be returned, usually a processor register designated for that purpose.

In the case in the question, with the functions in the same source file, the compiler can see there is undefined behavior. When compiling with optimization off, the compiler may act as described above. When optimization is on, a good compiler will see the code has undefined behavior. Then what happens depends on the design of the compiler. Likely behaviors include:

1. The compiler reports the problem and stops compiling.
2. The compiler eliminates some of the code it would otherwise generate. For example, it might remove the code that calls `func` but leave the `printf`.
3. The compiler eliminates all of the code on the path with undefined behavior.
4. The compiler replaces code on the path with undefined behavior with an instruction that generates a trap.

In case 3, it might take out everything in `main` but leave the return. That is not actually quite everything, since the return is left. I have seen a compiler actually remove everything in `main`, leaving just an entry point with nothing to stop the code from continuing on into whatever is linked into memory after it.

Case 2 can have some interesting effects. Without the undefined behavior, the normal sequence would be:

1. Call `func`.
2. Copy the value from the register (say `eax`) used to return it to the register used to pass it to `printf` (say `esi`).
3. Call `printf`.

With undefined behavior in the code, the compiler might remove 1 and 2 but leave 3. In this case, the program will print the value in `esi`, not the value in `eax`. That is, it will not print the value that was in the register used to return values; it will print the value in some other register. That is important to know when debugging—one way undefined behavior may manifest is by treating things as if they have values coming from unexpected places.

Answer (score 0):

this is actualy due to the complier!

lets check this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int func1(){
        return 155;
}

int func(){
        int ff = func1();
}

int main(){
        int result = func();
        printf("result %d \n", result);
        return 0;
}
```

try this out, it gives `result 155`, this is wonderful, isn't it?

##### what actually happens here?

Answer: when you leave a function without any return value, it means you do not change the value of the register **R0** (kind of memory, a lower level language than C, called Assembly language), which is responsible of passing the return value to the caller function (this
is refered as [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)) the complier checks this register to assign it to the variable in which the function was called.
you have to dig more to really know what's happening when you compile your program.

I hope you this provides you a clearer understanding to what is behind  **undefined behavior**

Comment: Not all CPUs have a register R0.  And since the code in `func()` invokes undefined behaviour, anything can happen — even on machines with a register R0.  What you describe is one possible behaviour; it is far from being the only possibility.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't took into account many other factors, such as parallelism, the unpredictable kernel, other computational structures... It was only a simple example of what could happen. Thank you for the remark.

Comment: When the Standard was written, the authors recognized that many implementations would handle many corner cases "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment" without regard for whether the Standard imposed any requirements.  If some function `int foo(unsigned long x)` was specified as returning a value whenever `x` is prime, and falling off the end when `x` was composite, a function `bar` wishing to wrap `foo` might need to be written as `if (isPrime(x)) return foo(x); else goto EndOfFunction;` to be strictly conforming or to work on some obscure platforms, but on most platforms...

Comment: ...simply saying `return foo(x)` without regard for whether `x` would return a value or "fall off the end" would have been sufficient.  An attempt to make *non-trivial* use of a value that wasn't returned could behave weirdly, but if `bar`'s caller never used its return value in cases where `x` was composite, then nothing should care about wehther `foo` returned a value in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

When the C Standard was written, a guiding principle was that if there might exist some implementations where it might sometimes be difficult to handle some particular corner cases in a manner consistent with sequential program execution, those corner cases should be characterized as UB, on the assumption that compilers whose customers would want them to behave "in a documented manner charactersitic of the environment" would behave in such fashion *without regard for whether or not the Standard required that they do so*.  Consider a function like:

```
uint16_t test1(uint32_t x);

void test(uint32_t x)
{
  uint16_t temp = test1(x);
  if (temp < 65536)
    test1(temp);
}
```

On a 32-bit platform like the ARM, the platform ABI might specify that a function declared as being of type `uint16_t` must always return with R0 holding a value in the range 0-65535, but if `test1()` falls off the end, it might simply return whatever happened to be in R0 at the time.  A compiler generating code for `test()` might recognize that because `test1()` is specified to always return a value 0-65535, R0 may be copied to another 32-bit register without modification, and that value may be passed back to `test` unmodified even if it exceeds 65535.

Rather than try to specify what may or may not happen, the Standard waives jurisdiction on the basis that compiler writers and their customers will know more about their target platforms and application requirements than the Committee ever could.

Note that there was never any intention to invite compiler writers to use the notion that programs will never receive inputs over which the Standard waives jurisdiction as an invitation to make further inferences, e.g. treating a sequence like

```
x=test(y);
if (y < 65536) doSomething();
```

as an invitation to unconditionally call `doSomething()` if `test(y)` is known to fall off the end when `y` exceeds 65536, regardless of whether code actually does anything with the value stored in `x`.